# Marionette ItemView Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

My view structure moves from a Layout to an ItemView like so Layout -> CollectionView -> ItemView. In my Layout View I add regions onShow based on certain criteria and I create and show a CollectionView in a region, which works fine.

Here is the code for the layout:

```
  define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'event.aggregator',
    'app',
    'util/objectUtil',
    'collections/booking/tourCustomizations/PackageUpgradeCollection',
    'views/booking/tourCustomizations/OnTourChoiceListView',
    'text!templates/booking/tourCustomizations/onTourChoiceLayoutTemplate.html'

], function ($, _, Backbone, Marionette, EventAggregator, App, ObjectUtil, PackageUpgradeCollection, OnTourChoiceListView, onTourChoiceLayoutTemplate) {
    var OnTourChoicesLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template: onTourChoiceLayoutTemplate,
        onShow: function () {
            var onTourChoices = new PackageUpgradeCollection();

            for (var i = 1; i <= App.numberOfItineraryDays; i++) {
                onTourChoices.set(
                    _(this.collection.filter(function (packageUpgrade) {
                        var serviceOrder = packageUpgrade.serviceOrder;
                        var serviceType = packageUpgrade.serviceType;
                        var isOnTourChoice =  serviceOrder.get('id') == 2 && serviceType.get('id') != 19 && packageUpgrade.get('serviceDay') == i;
                        return isOnTourChoice;
                    })).map(function (onTourChoice) {
                            return onTourChoice;
                        })
                );

                if (onTourChoices.length != 0) {
                    //use the layouts region manager to add and get regions
                    this.$el.append('<div class="serviceDay' + i + '"> </div>');
                    this.regionManager.addRegion('serviceDay' + i, '.serviceDay' + i);
                    var serviceDayRegion = this.regionManager.get('serviceDay' + i);

                    var onTourChoiceListView = new OnTourChoiceListView({collection: onTourChoices});
                    serviceDayRegion.show(onTourChoiceListView);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return OnTourChoicesLayout;
});
```

The collection view and item views are much simpler and follow the adhoc pattern of rendering a collection in Marionette:

```
    // Filename: views/facets/FacetListView
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'views/booking/tourCustomizations/OnTourChoiceView',
    'app',
    'collections/booking/tourCustomizations/PackageUpgradeCollection',
    'event.aggregator'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Marionette, OnTourChoiceView, App, PackageUpgradeCollection, EventAggregator) {
    var OnTourChoiceListView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        collection: PackageUpgradeCollection,
        itemView: OnTourChoiceView,
        className: 'booking customizations during_tour_options',
        tagName: 'div'
    });
    // Our module now returns our view
    return OnTourChoiceListView;
});
```

Here is the Item View:

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/booking/tourCustomizations/PackageUpgradeModel',
    'text!templates/booking/tourCustomizations/onTourChoiceTemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, PackageUpgradeModel, onTourChoiceTemplate){
    var OnTourChoiceView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        model: PackageUpgradeModel,
        template: Backbone.Marionette.TemplateCache.get(onTourChoiceTemplate),
        templateHelpers: {
            getUpgradeType: function(){
                return this.serviceType.name;
            }
        },
        tagName: 'div',
        className: 'input_row select_row'
    });

    return OnTourChoiceView;
});
```

lastly here is the template for the item view:

```
    <script type="text/template" id="on-tour-choice-template">

        <div class="input_col checkbox"><input type="radio" checked="checked"></div>
        <div class="input_col full_text"><strong>Day <%= serviceDay %> <%= getUpgradeType() %>:<%= description %></div>

</script>
```

This is the same way I've always rendered views with Marionette, but for some reason after the list view is rendered the item view gets called and then just doesn't render at all. I've placed an initalizer in the item view which gets hit every time and also checked to make sure that the template is being called by requirejs properly. Everything works like it is suppose to. The only thing that I am doing differently than what I normally do is dynamically adding the regions in the layout view.

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is the PackageUpgradeModel module:

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/taxonomy/TaxonomyModel'
], function ($, _, Backbone, TaxonomyModel) {
    var PackageUpgradeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            id: 0,
            description: '',
            numberOfRooms: 0,
            price: 0,
            serviceDay: 0,
            title: ''
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this.serviceOrder = new TaxonomyModel();
            this.serviceType = new TaxonomyModel();

            var serviceOrder = this.get("serviceOrder");
            this.serviceOrder.set({
                id: serviceOrder.id,
                name: serviceOrder.name
            });

            var serviceType = this.get("serviceType");
            this.serviceType.set({
                id: serviceType.id,
                name: serviceType.name
            });
        }
    });
    return PackageUpgradeModel;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `PackageUpgradeModel` as the model attribute for the item view? It doesn't seem like it's a model instance. Isn't Firebug (or similar) displaying an error message in the console?

Comment: I've added the PackageUpgradeModel, it should be fine as I create instances of the Model in the PackageUpgradeCollection which get passed into the itemView. Part of the problem is I am not receiving an error in the console, it is just rendering the Collection View while the ItemViews are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

You're providing the collection view with a collection, and Marionette will instantiate an item view for each model in the collection. Therefore, there shouldn't be a `model` attribute in `PackageUpgradeModel`. Also, make sure `PackageUpgradeCollection` is a collection *instance*.

If that doesn't solve your problem, try creating a jsFiddle with code demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.. I was resetting the collection in the for loop:

```
 var onTourChoices = new PackageUpgradeCollection();

        for (var i = 1; i <= App.numberOfItineraryDays; i++) {
            onTourChoices.set(
                _(this.collection.filter(function (packageUpgrade) {
                    var serviceOrder = packageUpgrade.serviceOrder;
                    var serviceType = packageUpgrade.serviceType;
                    var isOnTourChoice =  serviceOrder.get('id') == 2 && serviceType.get('id') != 19 && packageUpgrade.get('serviceDay') == i;
                    return isOnTourChoice;
                })).map(function (onTourChoice) {
                        return onTourChoice;
                    })
            );

            if (onTourChoices.length != 0) {
                //use the layouts region manager to add and get regions
                this.$el.append('<div class="serviceDay' + i + '"> </div>');
                this.regionManager.addRegion('serviceDay' + i, '.serviceDay' + i);
                var serviceDayRegion = this.regionManager.get('serviceDay' + i);

                var onTourChoiceListView = new OnTourChoiceListView({collection: onTourChoices});
                serviceDayRegion.show(onTourChoiceListView);
            }
        }
    }
```

I moved the creation of the onTourChoices variable to inside the loop and all works now.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= App.numberOfItineraryDays; i++) {
            var onTourChoices = new PackageUpgradeCollection();
            onTourChoices.set(
                _(this.collection.filter(function (packageUpgrade) {
                    var serviceOrder = packageUpgrade.serviceOrder;
                    var serviceType = packageUpgrade.serviceType;

                    var isOnTourChoice =
                        serviceOrder.get('id') == App.taxonomy.getId('serviceOrders', 'Tour') &&
                            serviceType.get('id') != App.taxonomy.getId('serviceTypes', 'Presold Option') &&
                            packageUpgrade.get('serviceDay') == i;

                    return isOnTourChoice;
                })).map(function (onTourChoice) {
                        return onTourChoice;
                    })
            );
```